# How to executing string as procedure

Tags: delphi, procedure

i made button component in runtime and i want every button clicked there executing unique procedure.

for example

```
exec('showmessage('+quotedstr('hello word')+');');
```

How to executing string as procedure in delphi 7 like eval in php or livebinding in delphi xe3?

Comment: Delphi is compiled, so there's no such thing like `eval` in php, and you're maybe missunderstanding what LiveBinding is

Comment: Eh.  Delphi is not PHP...and even in PHP, `eval` is almost always the wrong way to go about things.  :P  Does Delphi have any equivalent to lambdas, anonymous functions, or whatever?

Comment: i tried to that but the problem is in executing the string as procedure because that string is saved in database.

Comment: you can use a scripting engine like http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx

Comment: Step away from the keyboard for a second.  You're doing so many wrong things at once, it's scary.  :P  Delphi doesn't `eval`.  Even if it did, eval'ing code out of a database is all kinds of brokenness waiting to happen.  Step back and think about what you *really* want to do...and how that's likely to be feasible in a language that can't interpret itself on the fly.

Comment: If you stopped trying to store *code* in a database, then the whole problem of how to execute it would go away. Consider that. Why are you storing textual code in a database (or anywhere, for that matter)? Consider a template system instead; the database stores various *values* that you plug in to your already-written functions, so you just have to pass a limited number of values to those functions as parameters.

Comment: Sorry all my questions are answered, I found Tfsscript1 component of FastReport. there is a Evaluate function that I can use. thanks for all the  suggestions

Answer (score 7):

Delphi has no such facility. It's a compiled language, and the compiler only runs on the developer's system; you're not allowed to distribute the compiler with your program.

Instead, you can use any of a number of scripting tools, such as [DWScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dws/). It supports a language syntax similar to that of Delphi. It has some built-in functions, and you can define others from the host program to expose in the script environment.

Comment: For scripting libraries, see [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/226135/960757)...

Comment: Finally I found Tfsscript component of FastReport. there is a Evaluate function that I can use. thanks the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is not possible in Delphi. It does not have an interpreter. What you need is to embed a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this while looking for an answer

http://blog.angress.de/cracking/dynamicprocexecution_delphi/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, and the link provided is not pertinent to this question